# Dispatcher.Invoke() vs not creating any thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

In a WPF application, what is the difference between calling a method directly vs passing it to `Dispatcher.Invoke()`? Based on what I have read so far, both are executed in the same UI thread, aren't they?

**Sample code**

Case 1:

```
public sealed partial class Window
{ 
    private void SomeEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        SomeMethod();
    }
}
```

Case 2:

```
public sealed partial class Window
{ 
    private void SomeEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(SomeMethod, DispatcherPriority.Send);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to give more context. If you're not already executing on the UI thread (e.g. it's a background task) then it makes a huge difference. Sample code would be helpful.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to call Dispatcher.Invoke from inside the UI thread (in contrast to Dispatcher.BeginInvoke, btw). Any more details?

Comment: @JeffRSon, that's what I wanted to confirm, if I understand you correctly. I have posted the sample code to illustrate the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question would only be meaningful if the code runs on the UI thread.  Clearly there's a *huge* difference if you call it from a worker thread.  And you use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke, not Invoke().  So let's work the "might be useful" angle.

Yes, the delegate target will run on the UI thread in both cases.  The difference is in *when* it runs.  When you use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() then it will not execute until your program goes idle again and re-enters the dispatcher loop.  Typically after your current method returns, it depends on how it got activated.

While that sounds rather pointless, it *can* be useful in certain cases.  Useful when the method is activated due to an event and doing something in the event handler is dangerous because of re-entrancy problems.  A classic danger is getting the event to fire again, your code will bomb with this web-site's name.  Or when code runs after the event fires that undoes what you did in your event handler.  Using Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() is a clean way to delay the execution of your event handler code.  This otherwise models the way async/await works in C# 5.

Answer (score 1):

you can use UI threads dispatcher from a background thread whenever you need an action to run on the UI thread for example update TextBox.Text

moreover
`Dispatcher maintains a prioritized queue of work items` so you can run an action with different [DispatcherPriority](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority.aspx)
for example you would like your action to be performed with  `Background` priority The meaning that the operations are processed after all other non-idle operations are completed.